# CM fonts with T1 fontenc

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, computer-modern

I noticed one odd thing and I'm curious to understand it. I typeset my document with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` but without loading the Latin Modern fonts as I usually do. This resulting PDF is undistinguishable when viewed on-screen (using Evince on Linux) but when printed on an HP printer the fonts look "thicker". Both using the default font encoding or loading the Latin Modern fonts bring back the usual "thin" look of the CM fonts.

What is the reason for the different rendering? I should say that the slight "thicker" look is not bad (except that the math fonts do not really match). There are other free fonts with superb math companion that I should try?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With T1-encoding you don't use the CM-fonts but the EC-fonts. https://texfaq.org/FAQ-ECfonts.

Comment: And unless you have installed cm-super, you will get these as type-3 (bitmap) fonts, which your HP printer might render "thicker" than the type-1 vector fonts you would get with the default OT1 encoding.

Comment: Thank Ulrike and Lev! Now I understand. And I understand also why I do not see the same difference when I compile the document on my Mac. I guess cm-super is part of the TeX-Live package I have on the Mac and that probably I haven't installed on my Debian box.

Comment: Hi Ulrike, I run into this today with \sffamily\tiny resulting into bold-like text with CM font. It would be great if you could expand on your answer, e.g. which packages to load. For me loading `lmodern` did it.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I think you discovered a bug/deficiency in the ec-fonts generally (with the bitmap fonts, ecss500 looks bolder than ecsx500 too), but this doesn't belong into this question.