# How to small capitalize a word in a section title

Tags: fonts, sectioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using \textsc{} within \section{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17830/using-textsc-within-section)

I tried `\section{abc \textsc{test}}` but it doesn't work.

I guess there must be some simple way to do it.  Is it impossible? Why devote my question? I don't care if the small cap is bold or not.

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \begin{document}

 \section{abc \textsc{test}}

 the above.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: My crystal ball tells that Latin Modern does not provide bold small capitals.

Comment: @Andrey: while Computer Modern (actually European Modern) fonts have them in the T1 encoding.

Comment: @Andrey - what if I would like to see regular small cap? how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your preamble the line

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```