# Change font family locally (using package with limited scope)

Tags: macros, chapters, small-caps

I want to be able to use small caps for chapter headings. According to [Using \textsc{} within \section{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17830/using-textsc-within-section) CM default font does not support small caps so I need to use:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

in the preamble.

However, this changes font for whole document. I do have quite complex set up and global setting causes few issues so I would like to get same effect as by using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in preamble (that is - to be able to use small caps for chapter headings), but only for chapter headings that defined created by using following macro:

```
 \def \centeredchapter#1{
    \chapter*{\centering{\LARGE \textsc{#1}}}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    }
```

Is it possible?

Comment: presumably (untested)    `\chapter*{\centering{\LARGE\fontencoding{T1}\textsc{#1}}}`

Comment: Well you can always use `\fontencoding{T1}` locally, but imho you should better solve your global problems with T1 encoding. T1 is a much better encoding than the default OT1

Comment: Using ``\fontencoding{T1}`` in macro as suggested by David and Ulrike works in my case. Just for clarity - is ``\fontencoding{T1}`` a Tex or LaTeX native command? I thought it is ``fontenc`` package command but it works without loading that package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Font encoding is built into the LaTeX format, the `fontenc` package mainly just gives an interface to setting the document defaults so you can use

```
\chapter*{\centering{\LARGE\fontencoding{T1}\textsc{#1}}}
```