# Small caps with \textsc in subsections

Tags: sectioning, formatting, small-caps

The code

```
\subsection{\textsc{Should be in small caps} $\cdot$ Normal tekst}
\textsc{This text is in small caps}
```

gives the output

[image]

The `\textsc` command works fine in normal text but not in a `subsection` title. As shown, I do not want to change the entire title format, only a small portion within. Thus I cannot find out to make a general `renewcommand` feature.

Is there a method to accomlish this?

My document head is the article type `\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}`

Comment: you will get a warning in the log about a font substitution, you are using a font set that does not have bold small caps.

Comment: [This automatically linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17830/using-textsc-within-section?rq=1) seems to be a duplicate?