# Compile LX fonts demo on LuaLaTeX

Tags: beamer, fonts, luatex

I want to compile the [LX fonts demo](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lxfonts/doc/LXfonts-demo.tex) on LuaLaTeX. Because I would want to use this font for my future presentations. Furthermore, I only use LuaLaTeX.

I'm not sure how to correctly proceed to rearrange the code to be compatible with LuaLaTeX and not pdfLaTeX. In addiction, I'm not sure if this is possible [because](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/lxfonts/doc/lxfonts.pdf#page=7):

> Personally I believe that T1 encoded fonts should be
> the only ones to be used, unless the user has access to suitable UNICODE encoded
> OpenType fonts, but this is out of topic since **these LX fonts can be used only by
> pdfLaTeX**, that cannot directly handle OpenType fonts.

I know that `fontenc` and `inputenc` are not necessary on LuaLaTeX then I commented out their lines in the preamble. Then I compiled the code

```bash
latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -lualatex ./LXfonts-demo.tex
```

Unfortunately, it failed with

```
Missing character: There is no μ (U+03BC) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!Missing character: There is no ₲ (U+20B2) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig;!] [16
```

Comment: I get no error with luatex if I (just) delete the inputenc line

Comment: you need fontenc to use T1 encoded fonts, even with luatex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove inputenc (keeping fontenc) you get:

[image]

[image]

---

The above is all you need for Latin but you also need to force legacy encoding for Greek. I think this is enough, but I can't read greek...

Declare LGR and T1, so change the fontenc line to

```
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
```

Force Greek to use the legacy LGR encoding

```
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont
```

[image]

Comment: Thank David! I commented out `inputenc` and the compilation is successfully finished. Unfortunately I noticed that the [Greek quote slide](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/fonts/lxfonts/doc/LXfonts-demo.pdf#page=19) is composed with [Latin chars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhwy7.png). **Did it happen to you?**

Comment: @miticollo try now....

Comment: Thank again! I notice another problem. If you compile with `latexmk -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -pdflatex ./LXfonts-demo.tex` the output is [different from the PDF on CTAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b1Nv.png) (on the left side a slide from `lxfonts.pdf` on CTAN, on the right the same slide has just compiled).
I don't understand if this is an expected behavior or not: after all `lxfonts.pdf` was compiled ten years ago.

Comment: different monospace, what compare the output of pdffonts on the two pdf? @miticollo

Comment: See the [diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/f7arz3oq/). It is done on previous slide (12) and as before on the left the original PDF from 2013 while on the right mine.

Comment: David, I found a solution (maybe). It seems that [`SFLTT8`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ps-type1/cm-super/pfb/sfltt8.pfb) is a font family in [cm-super](https://ctan.org/pkg/cm-super). But if you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` [you can't use](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11247/274163) the CM-fonts.

Now, **is it possible to use this font family on LuaLaTeX?** See it is going to be tough.

Comment: If you really want the original 7bit cm fonts then use OT1 rather than T1 but by then it's not clear why you would use luatex at all as you are disabling all its font features (but do have lua of course) @miticollo  But I think you misunderstood my referenced answer you can use cm-super with T1 encoding, you just can not use the original Knuth fonts (which are 7bit OT1 not 8bit T1)

Comment: I solved the problem on slide 12 adding to preamble `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texttt}{\usefont{OT1}{llcmtt}{m}{n}}` or changing `\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}`. Doing this `\texttt` uses `CMTT` as font. Anyway there is another problem on slide [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKcFa.png) and I don't know how to solve it.

Finally I tried the original demo on Overleaf (with TeXLive2014 + pdfLaTeX) and the same problems happen.