# Why are LX Fonts Compiled Incorrectly on pdfLaTeX?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, texlive, mactex

After [successfully compiled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/697516/274163) the demo of LX fonts on LuaLaTeX I noticed two issues with `\texttt`, one on slide 6 and other on slide 12. To investigate further, I decided to use pdfLaTeX to compile [the demo](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lxfonts/doc/LXfonts-demo.tex) with the following command:

```bash
latexmk -pdflatex ./LXfonts-demo.tex
```

Unfortunately, I encountered the same issues when comparing [the original PDF](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/lxfonts/doc/LXfonts-demo.pdf) and my output.
[image: 6](**Note**: I marked the differences with red circles on the right side of the image, with the original PDF from CTAN on the left.)
[image: 12](**Note**: I opened these PDFs with Acrobat Reader)

I also tested this on Overleaf with different versions of TeXLive (e.g., 2014, 2018, 2023), but the results were consistently incorrect.

I used `pdffonts -f 6 -l 6 ./LXfonts-demo.pdf` to confirm that there is a difference in fonts between the two PDFs. Specifically, for slide 6, I found:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
LRFRIT+leclq8                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes     68  0
QHHCYM+lecli8                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    139  0
WBXQQS+LMMono10-Italic               Type 1            Custom           yes yes yes    237  0
LWMIDP+CMSS12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes yes    238  0
```

While for the original PDF, it was:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
FERQHL+leclq8                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      43  0
QHHCYM+lecli8                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     106  0
PVXJCL+SFIT0800                      Type 1            Custom           yes yes no     192  0
LWMIDP+CMSS12                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no     193  0
```

I reached out to the font author, who confirmed that on his Mac with MacTeX2023, everything works correctly, and he obtained the same PDF as the one on CTAN.

At this point, I'm uncertain about the source of the problem. **Could someone else attempt to compile this demo on their computer and share their findings?**

P.S. I'm using TeXLive2023 (updated) from tug.org on ArchLinux.

## Update

As Enrico suggested I tried TL2012 using [historic archive](https://tug.org/historic/) and I got the same PDF that you can find on CTAN. So I also tried with TL2013 but the issues on page 6 and 12 are reappeared. **What is the difference between TL2012 e 2013? Maybe packages version?**

Comment: I compiled the demo with TL 2012 and the result is the same as in the PDF file in the distribution.

Comment: Thanks @egreg! I updated the question with my findings based on yours.